# How can i add cloudfront behavior path pattern which matched by querystring

Tags: regex, amazon-cloudfront

I want to add cloudfront behavior pattern like below (jpg can replaced various image type eg, gif, png ...)

/original/a/b/c/d/a.jpg?p1=1&p2=2 : match

/original/a/b/c/d/a.jpg : not match

i tried below but not working

```
"original/*?*"
"original/*\?*"
```

how can i do this??

please help me

[cloudfront](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhoso.png)

Comment: The issue with AWS, they do a few things differently. The path match does not support standard Regex. There is not match criteria for anything other than path/url, which means you cannot set a behaviour for query strings, headers, etc. That is where they have addons like Functions. It comes at a price! In fact the wildcard '*' matches subfolders, even if regex won't.

Answer (score 4):

Path patterns don't support regex or globbing. Also, it doesn't support query.

> The path you specify applies to requests for all files in the specified directory and in subdirectories below the specified directory. CloudFront does not consider query strings or cookies when evaluating the path pattern. For example, if an images directory contains product1 and product2 subdirectories, the path pattern images/*.jpg applies to requests for any .jpg file in the images, images/product1, and images/product2 directories. If you want to apply a different cache behavior to the files in the images/product1 directory than the files in the images and images/product2 directories, create a separate cache behavior for images/product1 and move that cache behavior to a position above (before) the cache behavior for the images directory.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html?icmpid=docs_cf_help_panel#DownloadDistValuesCacheBehavior

Answer (score -3):

From your samples, I think that you want a regex like this:

```
original\/(?:\w\/)*\w+.\w+\?.*
```

EDIT

Since you require a globbing pattern try this:

```
/original/**/*.*\?*
```

You can find more about the globing patterns here: https://globster.xyz/

Comment: thank you for answer. but not working. that's not globbing pattern

Comment: @박진영 I edited my answer to include the globbing pattern